# Create a list from a DataTable

Tags: c#, linq

I have a entity as follow:

```
public class MarketDataBEO
{
public MarketDataBEO()
{
    childDetails = new List<MarketDataBEO>();
}

public string MarketID { get; set; }
public string MarketHeirarchyID { get; set; }
public string MarketName { get; set; }
public string TotalMarketSizeCYM1GI { get; set; }

public List<MarketDataBEO> childDetails { get; set; }
}
```

the relation is between MarketID and MarketHeirarchyID

a child can also have another child list

how do i create a multilevel list ?

EDIT:

```
MarketID | MarketHeirarchyID
1             NULL
2             NULL
3             2
4             2
5             8 <--
6             5
7             NULL
8             7
9             7
10            8
```

Comment: @NavatKayAahe: English please

Comment: Where is the `DataTable`? What is the purpose of the `MarketHeirarchyID` property?

Comment: @AlexFilipovici i m getting the datatable using a SP.

Comment: What is it's structure?

Comment: @AlexFilipovici added the structure plz check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var dict = dt.AsEnumerable()
             .ToDictionary(
                 row => row[0].ToString(),
                 row => {
                     return new MarketDataBEO()
                     {
                         MarketID = row[0].ToString(),
                         MarketHeirarchyID = row[1].ToString()
                         // Other class members here
                         // MarketName = row[2].ToString()
                         // TotalMarketSizeCYM1GI = row[3].ToString()
                     }
             );

foreach (var m in dict.Values)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.MarketHeirarchyID))
        dict[m.MarketHeirarchyID].childDetails.Add(dict[m.MarketID]);
}

var result = dict.Values.ToList();
```

Comment: thanks if i need to include other columns where do i add them ?

Comment: you could add them in first statement, when you creating a dictionary

Comment: added :  MarketName = row[2].ToString(),<br/>
  but still getting no data in that

Comment: @SiddhantMahajan could you clarify your problem with adding?

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo-code:

```
foreach(var x in datatable.Select(d=>d.MarketHerarchyId!="").ToList())
{
    datatable.Find(x.MarketHeirarchyId).childDetails.Add(x);
    datatable.Remove(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var marketDataBEO = new MarketDataBEO() { MarketID = "0" };
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, MarketDataBEO>();
dt.Rows
    .Cast<DataRow>()
    .OrderBy(dr => Convert.ToInt32(dr["MarketID"].ToString()))
    .ToList().ForEach(dr =>
    {
        var m = new MarketDataBEO()
            {
                MarketID = dr["MarketID"].ToString(),
                MarketHeirarchyID = dr["MarketHeirarchyID"].ToString()
            };
        if (dr["MarketHeirarchyID"].ToString() == "")
        {
            marketDataBEO.childDetails.Add(m);
        }
        else
        {
            dictionary[dr["MarketHeirarchyID"].ToString()].childDetails.Add(m);
        }
        dictionary.Add(m.MarketID, m);
    });
```

[EDIT] Based on your updated info, here's a 2-step approach. First, you'd get all the rows inside a dictionary, then you'd parse the `KeyValuePair` collection and create your hierarchical object.

```
var marketDataBEO = new MarketDataBEO() { MarketID = "0" };
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, MarketDataBEO>();
dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
    .ToList().ForEach(dr =>
    {
        var m = new MarketDataBEO()
            {
                MarketID = dr["MarketID"].ToString(),
                MarketHeirarchyID = dr["MarketHeirarchyID"].ToString()
            };
        dictionary.Add(m.MarketID, m);
    });
dictionary.ToList().ForEach(kvp =>
{
    if (kvp.Value.MarketHeirarchyID == "")
    {
        marketDataBEO.childDetails.Add(kvp.Value);
    }
    else
    {
        dictionary[kvp.Value.MarketHeirarchyID].childDetails.Add(kvp.Value);
    }
});
```

Comment: getting "The given key was not present in the dictionary."

Comment: I've updated my answer. Maybe you have to order first the rows, so the nodes with a lower `MarketID` should be added first (I assume that the  markets with `MarketID` values appearing in the `MarketHeirarchyID` are always returned in your data table).

Comment: The List is ordered by MarketID only. But for one particular row the MarketID =30 and MarketHeirarchyID=289

Comment: _(...)MarketHeirarchyID is 289 and the MarketID is not yet present(...)_, so you have to define a strategy to manage these cases. What should happen with these _orphaned_ markets? They have no `childDetails` list to be added to.

Comment: all MarketHeirarchyIDs are present but just that its at the last of the list

Comment: updated the list . the highlighted row has MarketHeirarchyID as 8 its present in the table but at a lower row